# Inflating layout inside fragment

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I am using a FrameLayout to use fragments. Now in one of my fragments I want to create a dialog with a EditText. So I wrote this code for my fragment.cs:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.intro_add_new_project, container, false);

    ImageButton btnAddProject = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnAddProject);
    btnAddProject.Click += delegate
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        View DialogView = layoutinflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.setup_project_name_dialog, null);
        Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder ProjectNameDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ProjectNameDialog.SetView(DialogView);

        EditText editProjectName = DialogView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editProjectName);
        ProjectNameDialog.SetCancelable(false);
        ProjectNameDialog.SetPositiveButton("Continue", delegate
        {
            //My own code here
        });
    };


    return view;
}
```

Now I am having a problem with the 2x `this`. It gives the following error:

> cannot convert from 'Appname.Fragments.Intro_Add_Project' to
>   'Android.Content.Context'

What am I supposed to fill in instead of `this`. Don't forget.... It is a fragment!

Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**
The error I get is:

> {Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.   at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   <42dc777b518744fdae9988e94489a4a0>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod
>   (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
>   Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in
>   <42dc777b518744fdae9988e94489a4a0>:0    at
>   Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog+Builder.Show () [0x0000a] in
>   <6bc524e87f8f4e14ab823997c1f60345>:0    at
>   Appname.Fragments.Intro_Add_Project.b__1_0
>   (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x0005b] in
>   C:\Users\Alexander\source\repos\Appname\Appname\Fragments\Intro_Add_Project.cs:45
>   --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace --- java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:260)
>     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:407)     at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:302)  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:958)
>     at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native
>   Method)   at
>   mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6669)   at
>   android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6638)    at
>   android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:789)  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26145)   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) }

Comment: I am not Xamarin aware, but error message seems related to *View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.intro_add_new_project, container, false)* line. It seems that *inflater.Inflate* method is expecting an Android.Content.Context object.

Comment: No, the errors occurre at the 2 lines with the part `(this)` at the word `this`

Comment: You want me to answer this or is it solved ?

Comment: Not solved yet, the last part of my question is the errors I get when I try the solution of Leon Lu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should the `LayoutInflater layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.From(Activity);`

and `Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder ProjectNameDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);`

There is my code of fragment.(Do not forget the add `ProjectNameDialog.Show();` pop up the AlertDialog)

```
     public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, container, false);

        ImageButton btnAddProject = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnAddProject);
        btnAddProject.Click += delegate
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.From(Activity);
            View DialogView = layoutinflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.setup_project_name_dialog, null);
            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder ProjectNameDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
            ProjectNameDialog.SetView(DialogView);

            EditText editProjectName = DialogView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_name);
            ProjectNameDialog.SetCancelable(false);
            ProjectNameDialog.SetPositiveButton("Continue", delegate
            {
                //My own code here
            });

            ProjectNameDialog.Show();
        };
        return view;
    }
}
```

There is MainActivity.cs

```
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);
       var Fragment1 = new Fragment1();
       FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .Add(Android.Resource.Id.Content, Fragment1)
                    .Commit();
    }


}
```

There is running GIF

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I still get 1 error on the line: `ProjectNameDialog.Show();`.... I added the error to my question's update part!

Comment: Can you share a demo?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk There is my demo, you could refer to it https://github.com/851265601/ImageButtonDemo

Comment: Did you use a `Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)` with this activity like this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34692/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: I am not using Theme.AppCompat right now, but how can I use it **with an actionbar**? I already tried: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, but in my code I used: `ActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.setup_nav_bar);` And now it gives an error on that.... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Accordind to [Xamarin Online Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/), **LayoutInflater.From** method expects an **Android.Content.Context** object. So, assuming your fragment has been inherited from **Android.App.Fragment**, as [Xamarin docs sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/creating-a-fragment) suggests, **this** regards to your fragment not you application context.

```
LayoutInflater layoutinflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
```